# python: SomeStingLikeThis to some_string_like_this

Tags: python

I'm looking for a solution to convert naming conventions in python. E.g. input of SomeStringLikeThis will give output of some_string_like_this.

Is there a pythonic way to achieve the above? I'm expecting some magical answers from python guru here. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with

```
import re

def split_caps(s):
    return "_".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)).lower()

print split_caps("SomeStringLikeThis")
# some_string_like_this
```

---

This works because `re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)` splits the string into separate capitalized words ([as described here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-October/032903.html)):

```
re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s)
# ['Some', 'String', 'Like', 'This']
```

`"_".join` joins a list with `_` characters, so

```
"_".join(re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', s))
# Some_String_Like_This
```

and `.lower()` makes a string lowercase.